# Plane intersection -2 (Vector graphics in Asymptote)

Tags: compiling, texstudio, 3d, asymptote

This is a follow up after my own [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339032/planes-intersection-in-asymptote). Back when the following MWE 
worked and compiled correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
import three;
import bsp;
texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
triple A=asd[1];
triple B=asd[0];

triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
triple C=asf[1];
triple D=asf[0];

triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
triple E=asg[1];
triple F=asg[0];

path3 q11=(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle);
surface sq11=surface(q11);
draw(sq11,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C--cycle);

path3 q21=rotate(-28,X)*q11;
surface sq21=surface(q21);
draw(sq21,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(rotate(-28,X)*(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle));

path3 q31=(D--C--A--B--cycle);
surface sq31=surface(q31);
draw(sq31,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D--C--A--B--cycle);

path3 q34=(C -- D -- rotate(-56,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);
surface sq34=surface(q34);
draw(sq34,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(C -- D -- rotate(-56,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);

path3 q22=(C -- D -- rotate(-28,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-28,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);
surface sq22=surface(q22);
draw(sq22,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(C -- D -- rotate(-28,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-28,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);

path3 q12=(D -- C -- E -- F -- cycle);
surface sq12=surface(q12);
draw(sq12,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(q12);

surface s4=surface(pl3);
draw(s4,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(pl3);

path3 q32=(rotate(-56,X)*(D-Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C-Y) -- A -- B -- cycle);
surface sq32=surface(q32);
draw(sq32,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(rotate(-56,X)*(D-Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C-Y) -- A -- B -- cycle);

path3 q13=(Y -- C+Y -- E -- F -- cycle);
surface sq13=surface(q13);
draw(sq13,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(Y -- C+Y -- E -- F -- cycle);

dot(A,red);
dot(B,red);
dot(C,red);
dot(D,red);
dot(E,red);
dot(F,red);

//From Charles Staats's tutorial
//Direction of a point toward the camera.
triple cameradirection(triple pt, projection P=currentprojection) {
  if (P.infinity) {
    return unit(P.camera);
  } else {
    return unit(P.camera - pt);
  }
}

//Move a point closer to the camera.
triple towardcamera(triple pt, real distance=1, projection P=currentprojection) {
  return pt + distance * cameradirection(pt, P);
}

label("$A$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((A)));
label("$B$",align=S,position=towardcamera((B)));
label("$C$",align=SE,position=towardcamera((C)));
label("$D$",align=SW,position=towardcamera((D)));
label("$E$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((E)));
label("$F$",align=S,position=towardcamera((F)));
\end{asy}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
import three;
import bsp;
texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
triple A=asd[1];
triple B=asd[0];

triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
triple C=asf[1];
triple D=asf[0];

triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
triple E=asg[1];
triple F=asg[0];

path3 q11=(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle);
surface sq11=surface(q11);
draw(sq11,red+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C--cycle,red);

path3 q21=rotate(-28,X)*q11;
surface sq21=surface(q21);
draw(sq21,blue+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(rotate(-28,X)*(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle),blue);

path3 q31=(D--C--A--B--cycle);
surface sq31=surface(q31);
draw(sq31,green+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D--C--A--B--cycle,green);

path3 q34=(C -- D -- rotate(-56,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);
surface sq34=surface(q34);
draw(sq34,green+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(C -- D -- rotate(-56,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle,green);

path3 q22=(C -- D -- rotate(-28,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-28,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle);
surface sq22=surface(q22);
draw(sq22,blue+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(C -- D -- rotate(-28,X)*(D+Y) -- rotate(-28,X)*(C+Y) -- cycle,blue);

path3 q12=(D -- C -- E -- F -- cycle);
surface sq12=surface(q12);
draw(sq12,red+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(q12,red);

surface s4=surface(pl3);
draw(s4,yellow+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(pl3,yellow);

path3 q32=(rotate(-56,X)*(D-Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C-Y) -- A -- B -- cycle);
surface sq32=surface(q32);
draw(sq32,green+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(rotate(-56,X)*(D-Y) -- rotate(-56,X)*(C-Y) -- A -- B -- cycle,green);

path3 q13=(Y -- C+Y -- E -- F -- cycle);
surface sq13=surface(q13);
draw(sq13,red+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(Y -- C+Y -- E -- F -- cycle,red);

dot(A,red);
dot(B,red);
dot(C,red);
dot(D,red);
dot(E,red);
dot(F,red);

//From Charles Staats's tutorial
//Direction of a point toward the camera.
triple cameradirection(triple pt, projection P=currentprojection) {
  if (P.infinity) {
    return unit(P.camera);
  } else {
    return unit(P.camera - pt);
  }
}

//Move a point closer to the camera.
triple towardcamera(triple pt, real distance=1, projection P=currentprojection) {
  return pt + distance * cameradirection(pt, P);
}

label("$A$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((A)));
label("$B$",align=S,position=towardcamera((B)));
label("$C$",align=SE,position=towardcamera((C)));
label("$D$",align=SW,position=towardcamera((D)));
label("$E$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((E)));
label("$F$",align=S,position=towardcamera((F)));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I have an issue for no reason. When I compile exactly that MWE, a black empty window appears and then quickly disappears in the first run.

[image]

It doesn't appear anymore in the following compiling runs (I use TexStudio). In the output document there appears just a space reserved for the picture. Nothing else.

[image]

If I change settings.render = 0; into settings.render = 16; everything works:

[image]

But I must use vector graphics. This is a publishing house requirement. Apparently, this is a problem with compilation, not with Asymptote. How to fix this? I need vector picture as it used to be. 
@cfr, @CharlesStaats.

%==== UPDATE =======

By @CharlesStaats suggestion I used this superminimal working example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
Hello!

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{asy}
        settings.outformat = "pdf";
        settings.prc = false;
        settings.render = 16;
        import three;
        import bsp;
        texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
        size(5cm, 0);
        currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

        path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
        path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
        path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
        path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

        draw (pl);
        draw (pl1);
        draw (pl2);
        draw (pl3);

        triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
        triple A=asd[1];
        triple B=asd[0];

        triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
        triple C=asf[1];
        triple D=asf[0];

        triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
        triple E=asg[1];
        triple F=asg[0];

        surface s1=surface(pl);
        draw(s1,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
        surface s2=surface(pl1);
        draw(s2,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
        surface s3=surface(pl2);
        draw(s3,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
        surface s4=surface(pl3);
        draw(s4,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);


        draw(B--A);
        draw(C--D);
        draw(E--F);

        dot(A,red);
        dot(B,red);
        dot(C,red);
        dot(D,red);
        dot(E,red);
        dot(F,red);

        //From Charles Staats's tutorial
        //Direction of a point toward the camera.
        triple cameradirection(triple pt, projection P=currentprojection) {
        if (P.infinity) {
        return unit(P.camera);
        } else {
        return unit(P.camera - pt);
        }
        }

        //Move a point closer to the camera.
        triple towardcamera(triple pt, real distance=1, projection P=currentprojection) {
        return pt + distance * cameradirection(pt, P);
        }

        label("$A$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((A)));
        label("$B$",align=S,position=towardcamera((B)));
        label("$C$",align=SE,position=towardcamera((C)));
        label("$D$",align=SE,position=towardcamera((D)));
        label("$E$",align=NE,position=towardcamera((E)));
        label("$F$",align=S,position=towardcamera((F)));
        \end{asy}

    \end{figure}

Hello world!
\end{document}
```

The black window is back. Output:
[image]

BUT! This is NOT vector graphics! (settings.render = 16;)

With settings.render = 0 works weirdly: 
[image]

After placing the document.tex (standard for TexStudio) into home-folder and starting

```
asy -vv document.tex
```

this is what the terminal gives (apparently a haven't change a symbol in the code):
[image]

Maybe I should install the newest asymptote like it was suggested here in comments (somebody erased that comment for some reason.) I even [asked the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529656/how-to-install-asymptote-in-ubuntu) how to do it. Nobody has answers yet.

Comment: If you need to draw the plane segments by hand, you could consider doing it with Ti*k*Z, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509163.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although he previous example works, but not on my machine (even though it used to) and I want to understand why.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I recently encountered similar problems with `asymptote`, which is why I upvoted the question. My point was simply that, if you cannot solve the problem in time, you may temporarily switch to other methods to generate the vector graphics.

Comment: What happens if you try copying the asymptote code (everything inside `\begin{asy}...\end{asy}`) into its own file and run `asy` on that directly? Better yet, run `asy -vv [filename]`, where the `-vv` will raise the verbosity level, and show us what is printed on the terminal.