# Opacity in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

Consider a MWE:

[image]

This is part of some diagram, so it looks unfinished, but never mind. I tried to make the example really minimal working.

```
\documentclass{article}%
%============================================================
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%============================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 16;
import three;
import bsp;
texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
triple A=asd[1];
triple B=asd[0];

triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
triple C=asf[1];
triple D=asf[0];

triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
triple E=asg[1];
triple F=asg[0];

path3 q11=(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle);
surface sq11=surface(q11);
draw(sq11,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C--cycle);

path3 q31=(D--C--A--B--cycle);
surface sq31=surface(q31);
draw(sq31,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D--C--A--B--cycle);

\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

It works. BUT I want it to be vector graphics (publishing house requirement). When I change

```
settings.render = 16;
```

into

```
settings.render = 0;
```

('cause that's what makes my graphics vector ) it brakes:

[image]

If I keep it vector (settings.render = 0;), but comment all the lines with opacity options, it works:

[image]

but this is not what I want.

**How to make a vector picture with opacity option for these planes?**

Commented example for your comvenience:

```
\documentclass{article}%
%============================================================
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%============================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
import three;
import bsp;
texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
triple A=asd[1];
triple B=asd[0];

triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
triple C=asf[1];
triple D=asf[0];

triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
triple E=asg[1];
triple F=asg[0];

path3 q11=(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C -- cycle);
surface sq11=surface(q11);
//draw(sq11,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C--cycle);

path3 q31=(D--C--A--B--cycle);
surface sq31=surface(q31);
//draw(sq31,white+opacity(.6),light=nolight);
draw(D--C--A--B--cycle);

\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

For references: this is a continuation of [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529447/plane-intersection-2-vector-graphics-in-asymptote).

Comment: did you try running `asy` with the `-nosafe` flag?

Comment: At least here (Fedora 31, asymtptote-2.59-2.fc31.x86_64, ghostscript-9.27-2.fc31.x86_64) it compiles with no hitch, and renders properly (with settings.render = 16 and 0).

Comment: I tried old and last versions of Asymptote but it does not work with settings.render=0. (Ghostscript v1.50). If this example or the one of your previous question were ok with an old version and settings.render=0, reporting an issue is relevant.

Comment: @Thruston, I use TexStudio, so it compiles automatically. In the settings: Configure TexStudio->Biuld-> Build& View I have asy-chain. The asy-chain command is: txs:///latex | txs:///asy | txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi, but I dont compile it with terminal.

Comment: @vonbrand, I tried to install the newer version of asymptote and even asked the question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529656/how-to-install-asymptote-in-ubuntu. Nobody answered after my update, so I still have 2.41 and have no idea how to upgrade to anything higher. (ubuntu 18.04, asymtptote-2.41, I have no idea about my ghostscript)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this example was ok with a previous version of Asymptote or/and Ghostscript. It seems that transparency, render=0 and surface cannot work all together.

However there is a difference with the example in [Planes' intersection in Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339032/planes-intersection-in-asymptote). In this example you use the `bsp` package and transparency, render=0, bsp can work all together.
Your MWE it becomes

```
      settings.outformat = "pdf";
      settings.prc = false;
      settings.render = 0;
      import three;
      import bsp;
      texpreamble("\usepackage{euler,beton}");
      size(10cm);


      currentprojection=orthographic((5,4,3));

      path3 pl =plane((0,-2,0),(-2,0,0),(0,1,0));
      path3 pl1=rotate(-28,X)*pl;
      path3 pl2=rotate(-56,X)*pl;
      path3 pl3=shift(-0.3*normal(pl1))*pl1;

      triple[] asd=intersectionpoints(pl2,pl3);
      triple A=asd[1];
      triple B=asd[0];

      triple[] asf=intersectionpoints(pl,pl2);
      triple C=asf[1];
      triple D=asf[0];

      triple[] asg=intersectionpoints(pl,pl3);
      triple E=asg[1];
      triple F=asg[0];

      path3 q11=(D -- (-Y) -- (C-Y) -- C -- cycle);
      //surface sq11=surface(q11);
      //draw(sq11,yellow);//+opacity(.6));
      //draw(D -- -Y -- C-Y -- C--cycle);
      path3 q31=(D--C--A--B--cycle);
      face faces[];
      filldraw(faces.push(q11),project(q11),white+opacity(.5));
      filldraw(faces.push(q31),project(q31),white+opacity(.5));
      //draw(D--C--A--B--cycle,black+1bp);
      add(faces);
```

and the result is a vector graphic.

Vector graphic and 3D are very difficult to manage. With polygones it seems to be possible but needs some specific routines.

[image]

Comment: It did work on the older versions of asymptote. I try to compile your example (ubuntu 18.04, TexStudio, asymptote 2.41), gives the mistake: Process started: asy TestAsyPicFile-1.asy

GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

/usr/share/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: If I try to compile it without bsp package, the mistake appears as well: Process started: asy TestAsyPicFile-1.asy

TestAsyPicFile-1.asy: 44.1: no type of name 'face'

Process exited with error(s) This is obviously the lack of bsp, I think.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev `import bsp;` is not sufficient, it is necessary to use the `add` mechanism to draw any plane. In fact `bsp` is a 3D->2D process using the binary space partition algorithm, more or less the painter's algorithm. Planes are added through `filldraw(..)` commands, and at the end `add(faces)` returns in the right order the drawing of a decomposition of all the planes so that visible/hidden parts are well managed.

Comment: I understand. But what do I do wrong when I compile your example. It gives me an error as above

Comment: With svn version, my example is fine. You have an old version of asymptote with Ghoscript version >9.23. Try `-nosafe` option. But I do not understand why 1) you can compile your example (render=0) with transparency 2) you can compile the example on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339032/planes-intersection-in-asymptote.