# How to make this figure of intersecting planes in asymptote or tikz?

Tags: asymptote

I want to draw the following figure
[image]

available here:
http://mathandmultimedia.com/2011/05/25/intersection-of-planes-google-sketchup/
I found a figure similar to the last figure here:
https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/planes.asy
However, the planes seem to be of different sizes in the figure in the asymptote gallery. I don't understand the code, so I am not able to adapt this to my needs.
I found this answer: [Planes' intersection in Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339032/planes-intersection-in-asymptote)

However, I could'nt quite figure out how to adapt this to make the second figure above.

I would appreciate an answer with some comments that will help me understand the code.

**Edit:** I found a similar question here:
[TeX-SX-Question: Intersection of 3 planes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509160/intersection-of-3-planes?rq=1)

The solution is in tikz.  I will have a go at solving this myself using tikz.

Comment: You have had all necessary codes for the figures you want to draw. Try draw with plain style as cfr did https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339046/140722